# Divide the height of page for two blocks using CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two blocks: header `.AccountInfo` and content `.DebitsAndCredits`. They both should divide the height of a page and `.DebitsAndCredits` should be scrollable. Scroll control should be visible just inside of `.DebitsAndCredits` block and I try to do that but I have no idea how to do that without JS but I think this is possible using just CSS.

I published my example here: http://jsbin.com/peqetoseyi/1/edit?html,css,output (I am sorry, HTML is not clean here, I just copied the compiled HTML of my react app)

There is my problem:

```
.DebitsAndCredits {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 300px;
}
```

I should do it whithout `height: 300px;`. The height of this block should be from the bottom of `.AccountInfo` to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Flexbox and do this (see notes in CSS)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.App {
  display: flex;                 /*  added  */
  flex-direction: column;        /*  added - stacked vertical  */
  height: 100vh;                 /*  added - full height */
  max-width: 40rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.DebitsAndCredits {
  flex: 1 0;                     /*  added - keep half height  */
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.DebitsAndCreditsItem {
  padding: 20px;
}
.DebitsAndCreditsItem-name {
  font-size: large;
}

.AccountInfo {
  flex: 1 0;                     /*  added - keep half height  */
  overflow: hidden;              /*  hide if content exceed element  */
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.AccountInfo-name {
  font-size: large;
}

.text-muted {
  color: #636c72;
}
.text-success {
  color: #5cb85c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-reactroot="" class="App">
        <div class="AccountInfo">
            <p class="AccountInfo-name">Joe Doe</p>
            <p>
                <!-- react-text: 5 -->IBAN:
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 13 -->HTB0001234567
                <!-- /react-text --><br>
                <!-- react-text: 7 -->Balance:
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 14 -->3133.56
                <!-- /react-text --><br>
                <!-- react-text: 9 -->Currency:
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 10 -->EURO
                <!-- /react-text --><br></p>
        </div>
        <div class="DebitsAndCredits">
            <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
                <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
                    <!-- react-text: 17 -->Wendy
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 18 -->,
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 19 -->
                    <!-- /react-text --><span class="text-success">+10.5</span></div><span class="text-muted">Diner</span><br><span class="text-muted">10 January 2016, 12:20 pm</span><br></div>
            <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
                <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
                    <!-- react-text: 27 -->Danny
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 28 -->,
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 29 -->
                    <!-- /react-text --><span class="text-success">+10.5</span></div><span class="text-muted">Diner</span><br><span class="text-muted">10 January 2016, 12:14 pm</span><br></div>
            <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
                <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
                    <!-- react-text: 37 -->Joe's Pizza
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 38 -->,
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 39 -->
                    <!-- /react-text --><span class="">-31.5</span></div><span class="text-muted">134678943.88</span><br><span class="text-muted">10 January 2016, 1:23 am</span><br></div>
            <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
                <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
                    <!-- react-text: 47 -->Northwind Industries
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 48 -->,
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 49 -->
                    <!-- /react-text --><span class="text-success">+2310.7</span></div><span class="text-muted">Salary January</span><br><span class="text-muted">9 January 2016, 7:00 pm</span><br></div>
            <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
                <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
                    <!-- react-text: 57 -->Coffee and Cakes
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 58 -->,
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 59 -->
                    <!-- /react-text --><span class="">-2.5</span></div><span class="text-muted">468832.99</span><br><span class="text-muted">8 January 2016, 11:14 am</span><br></div>
            <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
                <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
                    <!-- react-text: 67 -->Albert Heijn
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 68 -->,
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 69 -->
                    <!-- /react-text --><span class="">-76.65</span></div><span class="text-muted">489923982.45</span><br><span class="text-muted">7 January 2016, 10:30 pm</span><br></div>
            <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
                <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
                    <!-- react-text: 77 -->Shoes and Jackets
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 78 -->,
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 79 -->
                    <!-- /react-text --><span class="">-89</span></div><span class="text-muted">567222.67</span><br><span class="text-muted">7 January 2016, 9:29 pm</span><br></div>
            <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
                <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
                    <!-- react-text: 87 -->NS Railways
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 88 -->,
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 89 -->
                    <!-- /react-text --><span class="">-12.2</span></div><span class="text-muted">89357483.76</span><br><span class="text-muted">7 January 2016, 1:45 pm</span><br></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the height of `.AccountInfo` (in my example 150px), you can use `height: calc( 100% - 150px)` for `.DebitsAndCredits`, which adds up to a height of 100%.

However, you need to add two more things: `margin: 0` and `height: 100%` for `html` and `body`, AND `margin-top: 0` for your first `p`tag.

That last one is rather tricky: `.AccountInfo` doesn't have any margin-top, but it gets the default top-margin from that first `p` element (due to the phenomenon of "collapsing margins"). If you set that to 0, the whole thing works...

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.AccountInfo {
  height: 150px;
}

.DebitsAndCredits {
  height: calc(100% - 150px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.AccountInfo p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="AccountInfo">
  <p class="AccountInfo-name">Joe Doe</p>
  <p>
    <!-- react-text: 5 -->IBAN:
    <!-- /react-text -->
    <!-- react-text: 13 -->HTB0001234567
    <!-- /react-text --><br>
    <!-- react-text: 7 -->Balance:
    <!-- /react-text -->
    <!-- react-text: 14 -->3133.56
    <!-- /react-text --><br>
    <!-- react-text: 9 -->Currency:
    <!-- /react-text -->
    <!-- react-text: 10 -->EURO
    <!-- /react-text --><br></p>
</div>
<div class="DebitsAndCredits">
  <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
    <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
      <!-- react-text: 17 -->Wendy
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 18 -->,
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 19 -->
      <!-- /react-text --><span class="text-success">+10.5</span></div><span class="text-muted">Diner</span><br><span class="text-muted">10 January 2016, 12:20 pm</span><br></div>
  <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
    <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
      <!-- react-text: 27 -->Danny
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 28 -->,
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 29 -->
      <!-- /react-text --><span class="text-success">+10.5</span></div><span class="text-muted">Diner</span><br><span class="text-muted">10 January 2016, 12:14 pm</span><br></div>
  <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
    <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
      <!-- react-text: 37 -->Joe's Pizza
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 38 -->,
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 39 -->
      <!-- /react-text --><span class="">-31.5</span></div><span class="text-muted">134678943.88</span><br><span class="text-muted">10 January 2016, 1:23 am</span><br></div>
  <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
    <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
      <!-- react-text: 47 -->Northwind Industries
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 48 -->,
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 49 -->
      <!-- /react-text --><span class="text-success">+2310.7</span></div><span class="text-muted">Salary January</span><br><span class="text-muted">9 January 2016, 7:00 pm</span><br></div>
  <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
    <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
      <!-- react-text: 57 -->Coffee and Cakes
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 58 -->,
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 59 -->
      <!-- /react-text --><span class="">-2.5</span></div><span class="text-muted">468832.99</span><br><span class="text-muted">8 January 2016, 11:14 am</span><br></div>
  <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
    <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
      <!-- react-text: 67 -->Albert Heijn
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 68 -->,
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 69 -->
      <!-- /react-text --><span class="">-76.65</span></div><span class="text-muted">489923982.45</span><br><span class="text-muted">7 January 2016, 10:30 pm</span><br></div>
  <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
    <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
      <!-- react-text: 77 -->Shoes and Jackets
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 78 -->,
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 79 -->
      <!-- /react-text --><span class="">-89</span></div><span class="text-muted">567222.67</span><br><span class="text-muted">7 January 2016, 9:29 pm</span><br></div>
  <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem">
    <div class="DebitsAndCreditsItem-name">
      <!-- react-text: 87 -->NS Railways
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 88 -->,
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <!-- react-text: 89 -->
      <!-- /react-text --><span class="">-12.2</span></div><span class="text-muted">89357483.76</span><br><span class="text-muted">7 January 2016, 1:45 pm</span><br></div>
</div>
```